Properties with ranges for a Typescript interface
Is it possible to build validation into an interface?
export interface MapCoordinates {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
}

Latitude and longitude should be a range -90 to 90 and -180 to 180.

In TypeScript you can specify ranges in types. There are a lot of ways to achieve this. This is how you can do it in different ways:

1. Using Union Types for Ranges
type Range1To10 = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10;

interface Example {
  age: Range1To10;
}

This approach works well for small ranges where the values can be listed explicitly.

2. Using Conditional Types for Larger Ranges
type Range<N extends number, Result extends number[] = []> = 
  Result['length'] extends N 
    ? Result[number] 
    : Range<N, [...Result, Result['length']]>;

interface Example {
  score: Range<100>; // Accepts values 0-99
}

Generates ranges dynamically for larger ranges without manually defining each value.

3. Using Numeric Checks in Functions (Validation)
TypeScript doesn't enforce runtime constraints, so you may need runtime checks:
interface Example {
  percentage: number; // Any number
}

function validateRange(val: number, min: number, max: number): boolean {
  return val >= min && val <= max;
}

// Example usage
const data: Example = { percentage: 75 };

if (!validateRange(data.percentage, 0, 100)) {
  throw new Error("Percentage must be between 0 and 100");
}


This approach is useful when constraints depend on runtime conditions.


4. Using Branded Types for Compile-Time Safety
type Bounded<T, Brand> = T & { __brand: Brand };

type Range1To100 = Bounded<number, 'Range1To100'>;

interface Example {
  score: Range1To100;
}

// Function to enforce range
function createRange1To100(value: number): Range1To100 {
  if (value < 1 || value > 100) throw new Error('Value out of range');
  return value as Range1To100;
}

const example: Example = { score: createRange1To100(50) }; // OK

Provides strong typing and validation at compile-time while ensuring runtime checks.
